# How to retain ordering asc/desc by column after reload PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have page with different view (list,folder and thumb view), each view has its sort button where you can sort it by asc and desc (a-z,z-a,old-new,new-old).

Since the default sort is a-z,

What i want to do is once i click the button z-a sort in list view then change to the other view(folder view), the sort mode in folder view also the same to the last click sort mode which is z-a.

But happened on my codes is every time i reload or change my page the sort mode always in default.

```
if($sort == 'asc'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_files LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_album_files ON tbl_files.file_id = tbl_album_files.file_id 
                                        WHERE media_type = 'video' ORDER BY file_name";
        } else if ($sort == 'desc') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_files LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_album_files ON tbl_files.file_id = tbl_album_files.file_id 
                                        WHERE media_type = 'video' ORDER BY file_name DESC"; 
        } else if ($sort == 'old') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_files LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_album_files ON tbl_files.file_id = tbl_album_files.file_id 
                                        WHERE media_type = 'video' ORDER BY DATE(ctime_datetime) asc, ctime_datetime asc ";
        } else if ($sort == 'new') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_files LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_album_files ON tbl_files.file_id = tbl_album_files.file_id 
                                        WHERE media_type = 'video' ORDER BY DATE(ctime_datetime) desc, ctime_datetime desc ";
        }
```

My codes can sort well but i want is every time i reload the page or go to other page the sort will remain the same that i click before the reload. 
 Any Idea? TIA.

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem, if possible give some snippet code you have so far. :D

Comment: Handle the sorting in php (or JavaScript ) - especially as there's no pagination here

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a 'sort' parameter to your URL which will hold the sort-by property.

Have a look at how stackoverflow structures their URL

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pageSize=15
```

Stackoverflow provides option to sort by newest, featured, votes, active, unanswered; and the URL parameter changes with each selection.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=featured&pageSize=15
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=frequent&pageSize=15
```

Use this parameter to sort your results. In the backend you can easily access this property by doing $_GET

```
$_GET['sort']
```

By default if you want to keep ascending sort have an isset check on this parameter and if it doesn't exist sort the results in an ascending order.

```
if(isset($_GET['sort']) {
.....
}
```

Comment: @Strawberry If OP is switching views - list view to grid view to thumb view using javascript, the above approach won't come into picture with each request; since the sort manipulation will already be handled on the first fetch request. If pagination on search results is required, backend controller should sort the results and the switching of views can be done by javascript - also only if number of results remain same across views.

Comment: Apologies; I mis-read your post. It's very much how I'd do it, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my experience, is to add an argument to the url in your sort buttons.  Something like mypage.php?sort=new

Then, in your PHP code, set your query up like this:

```
//set the bulk of the query
$mSQL="SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY";

//do a switch to determine what to sort by
switch($_GET['sort']){
case 'new':
$mSQL.=" mydate DESC";
break;
case 'old':
$mSQL.=" mydate ASC";
break;
case 'alpha':
$mSQL.=" namecolumn ASC";
break;
//set the default sort order in case $_GET['sort'] is not set or does not match our list
default:
$mSQL.=" sortcolumn ASC";
break;
}

//now, execute the query
$result=mysql_query($mSQL)
  or die("Bad query! ".mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

//do something here

}
```